# Azure Data Factory propagating parameters

Tags: azure-data-factory

Using the Debug on the pipeline with parameters throws a connection error but with Az Powershell the pipeline executes fine:

```
Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName "name" -DataFactoryName "name" -PipelineName "name" -ParameterFile "json"
```

The pipeline uses a Lookup activity that queries Cosmos after document identifiers that are handed over to a ForEach activity with a single Copy activity using the identifier to get the entire document then write it to Blob Storage.  Any way to grab the linked service parameters when debugging?

Comment: Do you want to pass values for linked service parameters from pipeline? and could you please add the information about the linked service configurations?

Comment: Propagation of parameters works fine from Powershell (ie passing a JSON file with parameter key/value). But a Debug run with same values faults. Would be helpful in Debug to see that parameters used by the pipeline, data set and linked service.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the above scenario with an ADLS gen2 linked service to a lookup activity.

[image]

When I check the connection of linked service in the dataset it will give connection error.

[image]

If we debug the pipeline at this time, it will give the linked service propagation error like below.

[image]

***The pipeline only supports to give value for pipeline parameters only, at the debug***. Other than those it will not give any option for giving values to dataset parameters or linked service parameters at the debug.

If you want to give the value for linked service parameter using pipeline dynamic content, you can use dataset parameters for this.

If a dataset parameter's default value is not given at that time, the pipeline will be validated only when we give that value in pipeline.

First create a dataset parameter.

[image]

Now give the dataset parameter to linked service parameter in the dynamic content.

[image]

Now, you can give the **pipeline dynamic content to linked service parameter** like I am giving the storage account name to the dataset parameter which will be the linked service parameter value also.

[image]

You can see my pipeline executed successfully.

[image]

Comment: Yes.  Passing parameters via the pipeline to data sets to linked services is fine and works when executing from Powershell.  So the handing over of parameters isn't a problem.  It is that when debugging (in the portal) something odd is happening whereby the same parameter values (used by the Powershell command) are not dropping down to the linked service.  My question is if there is anyway to see the parameter value used by the linked service (obs not in the data set or pipeline rather what it is at the linked service) in Debug mode.

Comment: Yeah, got your point. AFAIK, in ADF, pipeline won't have access to linkedservice parameters. So, in debug mode also it won't show any values of linkedservice parameters.